# Pythonically transforming a dictionary

Tags: python

I have 2 dicts:

```
dict1 = {'field1':'value1', 'field2':'value2',...... }
dict2 = {'field1':'value1_1', 'field2':'value2_2','field3':'value3_3'}
```

I want dict1's field1 and field2's values to be dict2's field1 and field2's values.

So i want dict1 to be: `dict1 = {'field1':'value1_1', 'field2':'value2_2'}`, BUT dict1 has many other key/value pairs that are not in dict2 and i want to keep those the same.

What is the most pythonic way of doing it?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this maybe:

```
dict1.update({key : dict2[key] for key in dict1 if key in dict2})
```

Or with a simple loop:

```
for key in dict1:
    if key in dict2:
        dict1[key] = dict2[key]
```

Comment: or `dict1.update( <stuff_from_your_answer> )` if it's important to update dict1 in place -- although your simple loop does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. But there's a new restriction, see updated original post.

Comment: I dun think this is syntatically correct. It spits out errors.

Comment: `try: dict1[key] = dict2[key] except KeyError: pass` might be more efficient if you can assume that more often than not dict1 keys will show up in dict2, I think.  But that's an optimization anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a dict comprehension:

```
dict1 = {key : value for key, value in dict2.iteritems() if key in dict1}
```

Edit having seen mouad's answer:

```
dict1 = {key : dict2[key] for key in dict1}
```