# conditionally adding dictionary entries from a second dictionary to a new dictionary while preserving new dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dicts- 
`dict1 = {'a':'value','b':'value','d':'value'}` and 
`dict2 = {'p':'blank','q':'blank','r':'blank','s':'blank'}`. Their keys are stored in two lists- `list1 = ['a','b','c','d']` and `list2 = ['p','q','r','s']`.  `dict1` might not always contain all key:value pairs.

I want to add entries from `dict1` to `dict2`, *if* keys exist in dict1 *else* I want "blank"

I wrote this code:

```
for i in list1:
    if i in dict1.keys():
        dict2[i] = dict1[i]
    else:
        dict2[i] = "blank"
```

This will give me `dict2` with keys from `list1`. How can I modify this code to preserve the conditionality but keep keys associated with `dict2` i.e., `['p','q','r','s']`?
**My desired output**

```
dict2 = {'p':1,'q':2,'r':'blank','s':4}
```

The number of keys will always be the same in the two dicts.

Also, is there a more pythonic way to do this?
I saw some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544357/pythonically-transforming-a-dictionary) but did not understand completely.

Comment: Could you post expected output? Just to clarify a few things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to update `dict2` if the item in `list1` is in `dict1` using the corresponding key in `list2`.

You can zip the lists and iterate over the keys in both lists, setting the value using a conditional statement.

```
dict1 = {'a':1,'b':2,'d':4}
dict2 = {'p':'blank','q':'blank','r':'blank','s':'blank'}
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = ['p','q','r','s']

for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    dict2[b] = dict1[a] if a in dict1 else 'blank'

print(dict2)
```

Output:

```
{'p': 1, 'q': 2, 'r': 'blank', 's': 4}
```

Alternatively you can use the dictionary's `update()` method and update all the values in one line:

```
dict2.update({b : dict1[a] if a in dict1 else 'blank' for a,b in zip(list1, list2)})
```

`update()` takes a dictionary of items. In the line above you are creating a temporary dictionary with a dictionary comprehension and updating `dict2`.

Comment: How does using the update() improve the code? Is it faster or is there another benefit?

Comment: @sheth7 I have updated my answer to give some info about `update()`. It's not any faster. It just allows you to update several items at once. Of course, the simplest solution is the for loop given in the answer by Aurel Bílý.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, you want to "map" the keys of `list1` to the keys of `list2`? In which case, you can `zip` the two lists to iterate over the two lists in order, then keep the rest of the code same. One small improvement is that `i in dict1.keys()` is actually the same as `i in dict1`.

```py
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    if i in dict1:
        dict2[j] = dict1[i]
    else:
        dict2[j] = "blank"
```